# What happen if we allocate the memory to a same pointer twice using malloc in c?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my code:
there is array of size 5. and I allocating memory to the pointer p using malloc function.
here I want to know what happen after re-allocating the memory to same pointer and after
free the pointer than what happen. and when my if condition is true or when it's going to
execute.

```
int main()
{
   int array[5] = {2, 5, 3, 10, 9}; 
   int *p = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int));

   *p = 5;

   if (-1)
   {  
      p = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int));
      *p=6;
   }

   array[0] = *p; 
   free(p);
   for (int i = 1; i < 5, i++)
       array[i] += array[0];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's going to allocate until process/machine crashes after a zillion memory leaks

Comment: if (-1) is always true.  Are you trying to check if malloc was successful?

Comment: @Lokesh Soni There is a memory leak.

Comment: Why don't you just do `*p=6;` and skip the unnecessary allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is not allocated “to a pointer.”

A pointer is simply a variable that holds an address, the same way an `int` is a variable that holds an integer value (within a range).

Given some `int x = 3;`, when the program executes `x = 8;`, nothing is done with the 3 that is in `x` before the assignment except to overwrite it. It is gone, and there is a new value in `x`.

Similarly, when a new value is assigned to a pointer, nothing is done with its old value except to overwrite it. The old value is gone, and there is a new value in the pointer.

After `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`, `p` contains the address of the memory that `malloc` allocated, assuming it was successful.

This memory is not “allocated to the pointer.“ It is not bound in any way to the pointer. We could then do `int *q = p; int *r = p; int *s = p;`, and we would have four pointers all pointing to the same address, and they would be identical. None of them would have any particular claim on the memory.

Alternately, after `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`, we could do `p = malloc(sizeof *p);`, and this would store a new address in `p`. The old address is overwritten. The allocated memory is still allocated, because nothing freed it. But the program has lost track of its address.

Comment: hey can you explain  if condition too? and as I can understand when assigning new value to *p  than the *p wouldn't point to value 5 that's why you said  lost the address.